# Rolling sum in specified range

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

For df I want to take the rolling sum of the Value column over the last 10 seconds, with Time given in seconds. The dataframe is very large so using dply::complete is not an option (millions of data point, millisecond level). I prefer dplyr solution but think it may be possible with datatable left_join, just cant make it work.

```
df = data.frame(Row=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),Value=c(4,7,2,6,3,8,3),Time=c(10021,10023,10027,10035,10055,10058,10092))
```

Solution would add a column (Sum.10S) that takes the rolling sum of past 10 seconds:

```
df$Sum.10S=c(4,11,13,8,3,11,3)
```

Comment: Fixed third number to 13 to reflect comment. So, third row has time 10027 and adds up values for last ten seconds (4 at 10021, 7 at 10023, and 2 at 10027)

Comment: When you say 'last', you mean the previous ten seconds ya? So for your data.frame, row 1 would be a sum of row 1:1. Row 2 would be a sum of row 1:2. Row 3 would be a sum of row 1:3. Row 4 would be a sum of row 3:4. Row five would be a sum of row 5:5. Row 6 would be a sum of row 5:6. Row 7 would be a sum of row 7:7? Am I understanding your goal here?

Comment: Yes thats correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function `sum10` which sums the last 10 seconds and use it with `rollapplyr`.  It avoids explicit looping and runs about 10x faster than explicit looping using the data in the question.

```
library(zoo)

sum10 <- function(x) {
  if (is.null(dim(x))) x <- t(x)
  tt <- x[, "Time"]
  sum(x[tt >= tail(tt, 1) - 10, "Value"])
}

transform(df, S10 = rollapplyr(df, 10, sum10, by.column = FALSE, partial = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
  Row Value  Time  S10
1   1     4 10021    4
2   2     7 10023   11
3   3     2 10027   13
4   4     6 10035    8
5   5     3 10055    3
6   6     8 10058   11
7   7     3 10092    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I wasn't fast enough to get the first answer in. But this solution is simpler, and doesn't require an external library.

```
df = data.frame(Row=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),Value=c(4,7,2,6,3,8,3),Time=c(10021,10023,10027,10035,10055,10058,10092))

df$SumR<-NA
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$SumR[i]<-sum(df$Value[which(df$Time<=df$Time[i] & df$Time>=df$Time[i]-10)])
  }

  Row Value  Time SumR
1   1     4 10021    4
2   2     7 10023   11
3   3     2 10027   13
4   4     6 10035    8
5   5     3 10055    3
6   6     8 10058   11
7   7     3 10092    3
```